# Play a video in MatLab

Tags: matlab, video, matlab-cvst

I have a problem in MatLab. I try to read a video, and play it, but I only read a part of the movie, and I can't control the frame rate.

The idea is to treat the image after that, and do real-time processing, so I can't save the image in a file to create a video later.

Here is my code :

```
videoFReader = vision.VideoFileReader('movie.avi');
videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer;
while ~isDone(videoFReader)
  videoFrame = step(videoFReader);
  step(videoPlayer, videoFrame);
end
release(videoPlayer);
release(videoFReader);
```

This video contains 2521 frames, and I only read the 372 first frames.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Edit : Can this be a codec problem ?

Comment: That code is effectively identical to the example given in the help for `vision.VideoFileReader`. I'm not sure this old scheme has a means of adjusting the frame rate. Is there a reason that you're not using the [`VideoReader`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreaderclass.html) class instead (old version of Matlab may not have it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, if this can help anyone, I found out that the 64 bits video codec aren't right, and were the problems. It seems that if I want to solve the problem, going back to matlab 32 bits is the solution...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the frame rate. Simply add a statement

```
pause(0.04);
```

in the end of the `loop;`

It will let you have 25 frames per second. Also try to use small videos in matlab.